# "In the east" VS "to the east"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

Today I come across a sentence in my book:

> There are more people farther away, especially **to the east.**

But if I say:

> There are more people further away, especially **in the east.**

Do the both have same meaning? Please explain.

Comment: Are you also asking about the difference between *farther* and *further* or was that just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

**to the east** refers to the direction: somewhere towards east, regardless of distance

**in the east** refers to **the region** found towards east - usually that region should be known to the speakers / listeners.

"Famous" regions:

- in the Middle East
- in the Far East